# Azure DevOps pipeline - authentication failure when trying to connect to private npm registry

Tags: npm, azure-devops

I am trying to use a npm package from a private repository hosted in a different Azure DevOps organisation. I am getting the following error on `npm install` step:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/2dfb2f0b-4d21-4268-9559-72926144c918, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodcus1.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated
```

My project .npmrc file looks like this:

```
@{scope}:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_packaging/{FEED}/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
strict-ssl=false
```

I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) on setting up the PAT token with Packaging Read & Write permission

I have tried connecting by setting up a service connection which did not work.

I have also tried to by adding the credentials to the project .npmrc file and that does not work either.

.npmrc file with creds:

```
@{scope}:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_packaging/{FEED}/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
strict-ssl=false

//pkgs.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_packaging/{FEED}/npm/registry/:username=ANYTHING-BUT-EMPTY
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_packaging/{FEED}/npm/registry/:_password=BASE64-ENCODED-PAT
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_packaging/{FEED}/npm/registry/:email={EMAIL}
/pkgs.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_packaging/{FEED}/npm/registry/:always-auth=true
```

I have regenerated the PAT numerous times with different scopes but none worked. (I am generating the PAT from User Settings -> Security in Azure DevOps)

I am able to connect to the feed from my local machine using the `vsts-npm-auth` package.

Answer (score 2):

> Azure DevOps pipeline - authentication failure when trying to connect to private npm registry

According to the document [Set up your client's npmrc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows), we need set the `.npmrc` containing the credentials in `$home` for Linux or Mac systems or `$env.HOME` for win systems in development machine instead of setting it in your the project .npmrc file.

> On your **development machine**, you will also have a **.npmrc in $home for
>   Linux or Mac systems or $env.HOME for win systems. This .npmrc should
>   contain credentials for all of the registries that you need to connect
>   to**. The NPM client will look at your project's .npmrc, discover the
>   registry, and fetch matching credentials from $home/.npmrc or
>   $env.HOME/.npmrc. Credential acquisition will be discussed in the next
>   section.

And:

> You should have a project specific .npmrc containing only your feed's
>   registry information that you discovered from the "Connect to Feed"
>   dialog. There should be no credentials in this file and the file
>   itself is usually adjacent to your project's package.json.

Besides, if you want use the hosted agent, you could use the [npm Authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops) task to certification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its working for me now. The only thing I did was regenerate the PAT token again using the same scopes. All the steps I tried in the original question works now. 
Very strange, I generated about 7 different tokens yesterday and none worked.

Comment: The npm authenticate part was the missing part in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add an explicit `npmAuthenticate` step to log-in to the private NPM registry using the pipeline's credentials before the step in which `npm install` / `yarn install` was called, like so:

```
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/path/to/my/.npmrc"
```